# Deploying Raid 0 on an existing setup

Tags: partitioning, raid

I have a server that's already in deployment and will be adding on a new hard drive.  Redeployment isn't really an option because the server is a quanta server and doesn't can't support a KVM.  Installation was done via PXE and unfortunately I don't have access to this system.

Would it be possible to expand the server from a single hard drive setup to a raid 0 setup without reinstallation?

The server is also deployed with a LVM.

Thanks!

Comment: What operating system, not that it matters, virtually every operating system requires RAID drivers in order to exist on a system with a RAID.

Comment: The operating system would be Debian Jessie.